# dynamic flesh/clothes interaction

Tags: physics

right now i've followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X26xROC9wao&list=PLht0LeoHjwm0uDBVf-45TdGMHQjwVGuWW&index=4

then i made a mesh with the shape of the breast and bound it to the body with surface deform and applied cloth physics, then i made it parent with the rig in the video,  that allow me to have a good jiggle physics and interaction/deformation with external objects but when I try with clothes the mesh goes thru the breast, i solution this by adding collision modifier on both but now it acts as if the breast was A solid object even if it's jiggling, and if I turn the collision of in the breast it acts as if the cloth is a solid object with cloth physics, what i want to do is that the clothes and the mesh interact dynamically, squishing the flesh, i also want to apply that to different parts of the body, like arms, stomach, etc, i tried with shape keys but the cloth physics dont allow me to modify the mesh once the animation is runing

my pc is strong enough to handle it, does someone know a way of doing it?

(edit): i forgot to say that i tried with rigid body physics and i couldn't make it work because i cant  make the proxy mesh stay in place when applied active rigid body physics and passive does nothing

Comment: If you need real cloth interaction, they need to be part of the same cloth simulation-- same object-- with self-collision enabled, and any differing parameters defined through vertex groups.

Comment: how do i apply different parameters with the vertex groups? the only thing i got is the same properties throughout the hole mesh, to be specific the proxy mesh that im using for the breast, stomach, etc, has applied a certain pressure parameters toget a natural jiggle effect, those settings are different for every part of the body and i made it work becouse they are all different objects

Comment: If you're using settings that can't be set with vertex groups, then one sim will always rule the other and the most you can do is pick which one rules.  The one with the collision modifier will rule.